# Fragment is not showing up in view for duplicate dynamic added fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have the following fragments setup:

`1` and `2` are tabs which contain `A` and `B` fragments respectively. There is a button in `A`, on clicking, it shows `C`.

**Working fine**: In first tab `1`, `A` is added statically through xml. On clicking that button, `C` launches fine and pushing the back button gets me back to `A`.

```
|__1__|  2  |
|  A  |  B  |
   ↓
|  C  |
```

**Failing**: In `B`, there is a button that opens `A` dynamically. Now on pushing the same button in `A` as previous case, but in this view, **`C` fails** to show up. I can see in adb that the data is loaded up fine but somehow it is not in view.

```
|  1  |__2__|
|  A  |  B  |
         ↓
      |  A  |
         ↓
      |  C  |
```

My code for the button from `A` to `C` is:

```
@Override
public void onReshareTextClick(View v, int position) {
    this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.feedContent,
            LikeReshareFragment.newInstance(feedAdapter.getFeedItem(position), Utils
                    .FragmentType.Reshare))
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Code for `B` to `A` is:

```
@Override
public void onPhotoClick(View v, int position) {
    this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.llMySnaps,
            FeedFragment.getInstance(sharedFeedItems))
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

**Issue**: Since, there are two fragments with same name, I suspect this line to be problematic `replace(R.id.feedContent,..` in tab `2`. It may be actually replacing the `A` in tab `1`(which is not visible) instead of the one in tab `2`. Is this correct and/or how to resolve this?

**Update**
I can confirm the above statement. `C` is actually showing up in tab `1`. Why is this happening? Since, android has two `A` (constant id `R.id.feedContent`) to choose from, how do I make it explicit to use the one that was launched by `B`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Android does a DFS on `R.id.feedContent` to find the view to replace in the transaction.

**Solution**
By assigning an `ID` to the view programatically, I was able to find the 
correct view to replace.

Set View ID:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.feedContent);
    coordinatorLayout.setId(feedID+10); // here feedID is what differentiates the two feed fragments

    return view;
}
```

Here is the call to replace fragment:

```
this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(feedID+10, openPostFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```